# Accessing array context in SOAP response

Tags: arrays, soapui

In **SoapUI** I have a groovy script to build an array with parameters I'd like to use in a *SOAP response*.

I have used the following command in groovy to set the Array in the context:

```
context.MyArray = MyArray
```

How do I access the array parameters within the *SOAP tags*?

I have tried `<Tag>${MyArray[0]}</Tag>` but it passes back an empty value.

Many thanks
Peter

Comment: Instead groovy script should update the request content directly

Comment: I strongly disagree. Yes, you CAN. But I believe you shouldn't. Placing variables like this, makes it transparent, that the value is coming from somewhere else. That may not be the case, when manipulating the request directly, and may be a source of confusion when/if a testcase fails.

Comment: Rao - when you say 'groovy script should update the request content directly', do you mean build the complete Soap message as a string within the groovy script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ${= some code } tag

Example:

```
<Tag>${= context.MyArray[0] }</Tag>
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, it turns out this piece of code is a variable that SoapUI can understand directly. So you don't really need the "="

Comment: why `=` ? , no need for it

Comment: Yes you need it. If you use ${ something } then "something" must be a variable. When using ${= something } then something can be code. Groovy or Java.

Comment: Hmmm. Just tried it, and you are right. Will need further looking into... BRB.

Comment: Ahhhh. Actually both are right. You DO need the = to enter code. Which this is. But this also happens to be a variable that SoapUI understands, which makes you not needing the =

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have managed to now get this working. I searched the internet and could not find any documentation on accessing arrays/maps from within the Soap response!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <YourTag> 
    ${context.MyArray[0]}
  </YourTag>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed is that it takes SoapUI a LONG time to generate a response when accessing variables from the context in the Soap response body - especially when using arrays.